# HttpContext Null When Using AddToRoleAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my people controller I have the following lines:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(PersonViewModel pvm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var person = db.people.Where(x => x.PersonId == pvm.PersonId).FirstOrDefault();
            var usr = new AccountController();
            usr.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(person.NetId, pvm.SetRole);
            person.CurrentRole = pvm.SetRole;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View(pvm);
    }
```

When using the `UserManager.AddToRoleAsync()` method I get a null reference exception here in the `AccountController`:

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

Why is HttpContext null? Is it because I'm instantiating a new `AccountController`? If so how else should I be getting at `UserManager` so that I can add a user to a role? How does one add a user to a role from another controller? Seems like this would be a common issue since user management is a thing people would want.

Answer (score 1):

So I had to pay a consultant to answer this question. Here is the answer.

Because both the AccountController and the PeopleController both inherit from Controller, where the HttpContext is set, I cannot instantiate a new AccountController because then I lose the context I already have anyway with the PeopleController. So the answer is that when calling UserManager from outside the AccountController all I need to do is use the following:

```
var usr = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

So for an example in the context of my code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(PersonViewModel pvm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                List<IdentityRole> roles = adb.Roles.ToList();
                var person = db.people.Where(x => x.PersonId == pvm.PersonId).FirstOrDefault();
                var usr = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                foreach (var x in roles)
                {
                    await usr.RemoveFromRoleAsync(person.NetId, x.Name);
                }
                await usr.AddToRoleAsync(person.NetId, pvm.SetRole);
                person.CurrentRole = pvm.SetRole;
                db.SaveChanges();
                adb.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: You should also consider creating a service layer where you make your calls to the database and return the data needed, instead of making those database calls in your actions. You will also get better separation of concers if you use dependency injection to inject your services to your controllers.